# To control first derivative with the function itself: $f'(x)^2\leq Cf(x)$ near where $f(x_0)=f'(x_0)=f''(x_0)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $f$ be a compactly supported nonnegative $C^2$ function.

I want to show that there exists $C$, such that for all $x\in \mathbb R$, we have $f'(x)^2\leq  C f(x) $ by showing that for every point $x\in \mathbb R$, we can find a neighborhood $U$, that on $U$ we can find such a $C$.

However I have a trouble to find such a $U$ and $C$ when $f, f', f''$ all vanish at x. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This reminds me somehow on self-concordant functions.

Comment: To add another perspective, this is basically related to the question what is the best regularity we can get for the square root of a nonnegative $C^2$ function $f$. For if $g^2 = f$ is differentiable, then for $x$ such that $f(x)\not=0$ we have $|g'(x)| = |f'(x)|/(2f(x)^{1/2})$, where $f(x)^{1/2}$ is the positive square root of $f(x)$. It would be sufficient for your purpose, then, to show that $f$ admits a $C^1$ square root. This is true (and sharp!) by [this](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~bony/BBCP_jfa.pdf) for instance. There are some references inside.

Comment: See also [this MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105438/square-root-of-a-positive-c-infty-function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such $f$ there holds an estimate $f'(x)^2\le 2Mf(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, where $M=\max|f''|$. See lemma 5.6 in [Yu. V. Egorov, Linear Differential Equations of Principal Type](http://books.google.ru/books?id=UxaoAAAAIAAJ).

The idea is to consider $f$ on an interval $(x_1,x_2)$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are consecutive zeros of $f$. 
If the maximum of $f'^2/f$ on $[x_1,x_2]$ is attained at some  $c\in(x_1,x_2)$, then
$$2f''(c)f(c)-f'^2(c)=0$$ and $f'^2(x)\le 2f(x)|f''(c)|\,$ on $[x_1,x_2]$.

For endpoints L'Hopital's rule is used:
$$
\lim_{x\to x_1}\frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to x_1}\frac{2f''(x)f'(x)}{f'(x)}=2f''(x_1).
$$

Answer (score 4):

There is an $M>0$ with $$|f''(x)|\leq M\qquad\forall\>x\in{\mathbb R}\ .\tag{1}$$ 
*Claim:* $\quad f'^2(x)\leq 2M \>f(x)\quad\forall x\in{\mathbb R}$.

*Proof.* $\ $ When $f(x)=0$ at some point $x\in{\mathbb R}$ then $f'(x)=0$ as well, since otherwise $f$ would assume negative values in some points.

Therefore it is enough to show that $f(0)=:y_0>0$ and $f'(0)=-m_0$ with
$$m_0^2>2My_0\tag{2}$$
is *impossible*. Assume to the contrary that these conditions hold. From $(1)$ we then get
$$f'(x)\leq-m_0+Mx\qquad(x\geq0)\tag{3}$$
and therefore
$$f(x)=y_0+\int_0^x f'(t)\>dt\leq y_0+\int_0^x(-m_0+Mt)\>dt=y_0-m_0x+{1\over2}Mx^2\qquad(x\geq0)\ .$$
Putting $x:={m_0\over M}$ here it follows from $(2)$  that
$$f\left(m_0\over M\right)\leq y_0-{m_0^2\over 2M}<0\ .$$
From this we conclude that $f(\xi)=0$ for a $\xi$ with $0<\xi<{m_0\over M}$. At the same time, from $(3)$ it would  follow that $f'(\xi)<0$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat : there is a flaw in the proof below as explained in the comments.

Your conjecture is false, as I show below.
My proof is conceptually straightforward but there are probably
more elegant and computationally simpler counterexamples.
If one removes the positivity condition on your function, a "canonical" counterexample
can be proved to exist by mere abstract algebra without any computation.
But we are lucky : the algebraic counterexample happens to be positive also
(hence the names "lucky lemma" below).

The basic idea is rather simple : we are going to construct a
$C^2$ function supported on $[0,2]$, such that 
$f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n^3},f'(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n},
f''(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for any $n\geq 1$.

Denote by ${\mathbb R}_5[X]$ the space of polynomials of 
degree $\leq 5$ in $X$.

**Lemma 1.** Let $a < b$ be two real numbers. Given a uple
$v\in{\mathbb R}^6$, there is a unique polynomial $P\in {\mathbb R}_5[X]$ 
such that $(P(a),P'(a),P''(a),P(b),P'(b),P''(b))=v$. We denote this
polynomial by $L(a,b,v)$.

**Proof of lemma 1.** We must show that
The linear map $\phi : {\mathbb R}_5[X] \to {\mathbb R}^6$,
$P\mapsto (P(a),P'(a),P''(a),P(b),P'(b),P''(b))$ is an isomorphism. Since the dimensions coincide, 
it suffices to show
 that the kernel of $\phi$ is trivial. But any $P\in {\sf Ker}(\phi)$
 must be a multiple of $(X-a)^3(X-b)^3$, and the conclusion follows.

**Lemma 2 (Easy lucky lemma)** The polynomial
$R=L(1,2,(1,1,0,0,0,0))$ is positive on $[1,2)$.

**Proof of lemma 2.** This polynomial is $R(x)=(2-x)^3\left((3x-\frac{7}{3})^2+\frac{5}{9}\right)$

**Lemma 3 (Hard lucky lemma)** The polynomial
$Q_n=L(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n},(\frac{1}{(n+1)^3},\frac{1}{n+1},0,\frac{1}{n^3},\frac{1}{n},0))$ 
is positive on $[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$.

**Proof of lemma 3.** We can write 
$$Q_n(x)=\frac{1-nx}{(n+1)^2}+\big(x-\frac{1}{n+1}\big)\bigg(\frac{2n+1}{n+1}(1-nx)+
\big(x-\frac{1}{n+1}\big)T_n(x)\bigg)$$ where $T_n$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ in $x$ ,
and $T_n\geq 0$ on $[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$ (I'll add more details on this last 
point later).

Finally, we can construct $f$ as follows :

$$
f(x)=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
0, &\text{if} & x\leq 0, \\
Q_n(x), &\text{if} & x\in[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}],n\geq 1, \\
R(x), &\text{if} & x\in[1,2], \\
0, &\text{if} & x\geq 2. \\
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: According to Mathematica, $T_n(x) = 2 \left(3 n^4-14 n^2-15 n-5\right)-3 n^2 (n+1)^2 \left(2 n^3-3 n^2-5 n-2\right) x^3+n (n+1) \left(18 n^4-12 n^3-68 n^2-56 n-15\right) x^2-\left(18 n^5+3 n^4-81 n^3-110 n^2-56 n-10\right) x$.  I don't know why it's positive on $[1/(n+1),1/n]$, but otherwise this looks great.

Comment: Another detail I don't know: How do we show that twice differentiability extends to $0$?  We need $\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to0+}f'(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to0+}f''(x)=0$, requiring upper bounds of $Q_n$, $Q_n'$, and $Q_n''$ on $[1/(n+1),1/n]$ going to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thank you for reminding me of that. Unfortunately, I just found that the supremum of ${Q''}_n$ on $[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$ tends to $\infty$ as $n\to+\infty$. I'll see if this can be salvaged.

Comment: OK, so this example isn't $C^2$, and Andrew has shown the conjecture is true.  Still an interesting example/technique.  And I'm curious, do you know if $f$ is twice differentiable?  (If so we know $f''(0)=0$ but $\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}f''(x)$ doesn't exist.)