# Bound on first derivative $\max \left(\frac{|f'(x)|^2}{f(x)} \right) \le 2 \max |f''(x)|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I want to show that for a function $f \in C_c^2((a,b))$ non-negative, the inequality 
$$\sup \left(\frac{|f'(x)|^2}{f(x)} \right) \le 2 \sup |f''(x)|$$
holds.

I noticed that the left term is equal to  $2 |\sqrt{f(x)}'|^2.$ So the question is equivalent to: Can I bound this term just by the second derivative? Currently, I don't see how this could work.

The problem I am also having with the exercise is that we get problems if $f(x)=0$ cause then we may divide zero by zero on the left-hand side and it is not immediate to me that the limit is finite.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Is this even correct? on $[1,2]$ with $f(x)=x$, $f'(x)=1$, $f''(x)=0$, your lhs is $2$ and your rhs is $0$… there exists a similar inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_inequality

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf sorry forgot the compact support

Comment: if $[a,b]$ replace $R$ is also true. It is famous inequality $$M_{1}\le \sqrt{2M_{0}M_{2}},M_{i}=sup \{|f^{(i)}(x)|\}<+\infty$$

Comment: @math110 okay, how do you show this?

Comment: @math110, your “famous” inequality is a particular case of the LK-inequalities. Here, OP's question is not exactly the same (yet looks similar or related).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf,I think is same, why is not same?

Comment: @math110 because here it's about the max of $|f'|^2/f$ and not about the max of $|f'|^2$ divided by the max of $f$.

Comment: ok,I have understand.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio as you can see in the comment section, this questions is different from the one that you linked.

Comment: @Roadrunner324 I left him a comment on the other question (not sure if it's a good thing to do, but it's the only way I could contact him)—let's hope the question will be reopened…

Comment: possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883476/to-control-first-derivative-with-the-function-itself-fx2-leq-cfx-near-w

Answer (score 0):

I have use  proof by contradiction;

Assmue there exsit $x_{0}\in [a,b]$, 
$$\dfrac{f'^2(x_{0})}{f(x_{0})}>2\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f''(x)|\Longrightarrow 1-\dfrac{2f(x_{0})f''(\theta)}{f'(x_{0})}<0,\forall \theta\in[a,b]$$
Use Taylor's Formula,we have

> $$f(x)=f(x_{0})+f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0})+\dfrac{f''(\theta)}{2}(x-x_{0})^2,\theta\in [a,b]$$
>   Let $x-x_{0}=-\dfrac{2f(x_{0})}{f'(x_{0})}$

then we have
\begin{align*}f(x)&=f(x_{0})-2f(x_{0})+\dfrac{f''(\theta)}{2}\cdot\dfrac{4f^2(x_{0})}{f'^2(x_{0})}\\
&=-f'(x_{0})\left(1-\dfrac{2f(x_{0})f''(\theta)}{f'(x_{0})}\right)\\
&<0
\end{align*}
contradiction

Comment: your solution is full of errors.

Comment: Yep, lots of errors.

Comment: which is wrong?

Comment: @math110 Why is $f'(x_0) > 0$?  You also need to exercise more care at the boundary: to assert that $\theta \in [a,b]$ in Taylor's theorem you need that $x \in [a,b]$, which $x_0 - 2f(x_0)/f'(x_0)$ might not be.